# How should we handle history tracking transactions purging, if we allow users to enable/ disable CloudKit sync?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

Due to privacy concern, we wish to provide a toggle switch, so that user has the freedom, to choose whether to sync `CoreData` with `iCloud`.

We can implement such a feature by following suggestion from https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118924?login=true

However, we should not perform history tracking transactions purging, once user disables CloudKit sync.

Reason is that, if few months later/ few years later, user decides to turn on CloudKit sync again, lack of sufficient history tracking transactions, will cause CloudKit sync fail.

This is causing a dilemma. If we never clean the history tracking transactions, will it cause disk full issue?

***If that is so, may I know, what is the correct way to handle history tracking transactions purging, if we allow users to enable/ disable CloudKit sync?***

Thank you.